# how to apply unique_with_counts over 2d array in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, deep-learning

I have this tensor:

```
tf_a1 = [[0 3 1 22]
        [3 5 2  2]
        [2 6 3 13]
        [1 7 0 3 ]
        [4 9 11 10]]
```

What I want to do is to find the unique values being repeated more than a `threshold` across all columns.

For example here, `3` repeated in `4 columns`. `0` repeated in `2 columns`. `2` repeated in `3 columns` and so on.

I want my output be like this(suppose threshold is `2`, so indexes repeated more than 2 times will be masked).

```
[[F T F F]
 [T F T T]
 [T F T F]
 [F F F T]
 [F F F F]]
```

This is what I have done:

```
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(tf_a1)   
tf.where(tf.where(count, tf_a1, tf.zeros_like(tf_a1)))
```

But it raises the error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: unique
>   expects a 1D vector. [Op:UniqueWithCounts]

Thanks.

Comment: What about reshaping to 1D before calling `unique_with_counts`?

Comment: @a_guest thank you for your answer, that sounds right actually. after that I can again reshape it to 2d array. corect?

Comment: That should work, yes. Btw according to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16499) `unique_with_counts` should support an `axis` parameter (though it's not documented?). Could you check if it works nevertheless? Ah wait, but that doesn't help you, right? Actually, can you have repetitions within the same column? If so, should that count as a "duplicate"?

Comment: Actually per column I do not have repetition. I searched and found that `unique count should support multidimensional array plus axis but I could not find it in tensorflow website.

Comment: Ok then I think reshaping is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the API of `unique_with_counts` that supports axis is not public yet. If you want to `unique_with_counts` with multi-dim tensor, you can call it like this in tf 1.14:

```py
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_array_ops

# tensor 'x' is [[1, 0, 0],
#                [1, 0, 0],
#                [2, 0, 0]]
y, idx, count = gen_array_ops.unique_with_counts_v2(x, [0])
y ==> [[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0]]
idx ==> [0, 0, 1]
count ==> [2, 1]
```

Since I cannot comment @sariii post. It should be `tf.greater(count,2)`. Also, I do not think this solution is satisfying the requirement of the problem. For example, if the first col are all 2 and the rest of col don't have 2. According to your requirement, 2 should be counted as 1 times. But in your solution, if you reshape to the 1d first, then you will lost this info. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

[issue#16503](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/16503#issuecomment-481831053)

Comment: Thank you for updating with the new solution here. Actually, I have unique numbers per column so that solution will work. I belive your approach is more general. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `unique_with_count` should support multidimensional and axis, however I could not find anything in the documentation.

The workaround for me was to first of al reshape my tensor to 1d array and then apply `unique_with_count` and then reshape it back to the original size:

Thanks to @a_guest for sharing the idea

```
token_idx = tf.reshape(tf_a1, [-1])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(token_idx)
masked = tf.greater_equal(count, 2)
backed_same_size = tf.gather(masked, idx)
tf.reshape(backed_same_size, shape=tf.shape(tf_a1))
```